# Why does transition animation not work with block objects, but with deprecated animations API

Tags: iphone, animation

I'm trying  a flip or curl between to views in a container which works pretty well using the following code:

```
[UIView beginAnimations:nil context:NULL];
[UIView setAnimationDuration:.8];

[UIView setAnimationTransition:animationOption
                       forView:container cache:YES];
[container addSubview:nuView];
[oldView removeFromSuperview];
[UIView commitAnimations];
```

but does not with

```
[UIView transitionWithView:container
                  duration:.8
                   options:animationOption
 animations:^
 {
   [container addSubview:nuView];
   [oldView removeFromSuperview];
 }
 completion:^(BOOL finished)
 {
 }];
```

Any ideas?

Comment: Is there a specific reason why you pass in an empty completion block? As blocks are objects, I think it should work to pass nil there.

Answer (score 1):

What is `animationOption`? This code works perfectly well in one of my apps:

```
[UIView transitionWithView:currentContainerView
                  duration:0.75
                   options:UIViewAnimationOptionTransitionFlipFromLeft
                animations:^{ 
                        [currentContainerView.frontView removeFromSuperview]; 
                        [currentContainerView addSubview:currentContainerView.flippedSideView];
                    }
                completion:^(BOOL finished) {
                        // stuff
                    }];
```

Answer (score 1):

Check if you are using UIViewAnimationOptionTransition or UIViewAnimationTransition !